# Unlink a PC from Skydrive?

Tags: windows, onedrive

I have just lost a laptop running Windows 8 Consumer Preview with the Skydrive application installed.  I have changed my Windows Live password.

How do I remove the laptop from syncing to Skydrive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Log in to SkyDrive, and from the sidebar on the left click "Computers" => the name of your laptop. The page that loads has a "disconnect computer from SkyDrive" link at the top.

In your shoes I would also change my SkyDrive password and any other passwords given to  applications on that laptop.

Comment: Thanks very much Jon.  I have changed the password already.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Microsoft Surface (tablet) running Windows 8 RT, open your Skydrive account, move your mouse pointer to the far right until you see the pop-out toolbar (this can be tricky to get this toolbar to open, so move your mouse pointer to the top or botton of screen on the right side until you see it kick out) then click on Settings. When that opens, click on Options and then sign out of the account you no longer want to be in. Now you can log back into Skydrive with a different account. Yeah, this almost made me go nuts too in trying to change account I was logged into.
P.S. I have a wireless mouse plugged into the only USB port on this tablet, works great.